# What is the $n$th derivative of $f(x)=(1-x^3)^{-1}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am not entirely sure if this has been asked before, but I am trying to find the $n$th derivative of:
$$f(x)=(1-x^3)^{-1}=\frac1{1-x^3}$$
I first started by trying to look for a pattern:
$$\begin{align}f'(x)&=-(-3x^2)(1-x^3)^{-2}=3x^2(1-x^3)^{-2}\\f''(x)&=6x(1-x^3)^{-2}+3x^2\cdot-2(-3x^2)(1-x^3)^{-3}\\&=6x(1-x^3)^{-2}+18x^4(1-x^3)^{-3}\\f^{(3)}(x)&=6(1-x^3)^{-2}+6x(-2)(-3x^2)(1-x^3)^{-3}+72x^3(1-x^3)^{-3}\\&+18x^4(-3)(-3x^2)(1-x^3)^{-4}\\&=6(1-x^3)^{-2}+108x^3(1-x^3)^{-3}+162x^6(1-x^3)^{-4}\\f^{(4)}(x)&=6(-2)(-3x^2)(1-x^3)^{-3}+324x^2(1-x^3)^{-3}+108x^3(-3)(-3x^2)(1-x^3)^{-4}\\&+972x^5(1-x^3)^{-4}+162x^6(-4)(-3x^2)(1-x^3)^{-5}\\&=360x^2(1-x^3)^{-3}+1944x^5(1-x^3)^{-4}+1944x^8(1-x^3)^{-5}\end{align}$$
But that didn't help in any way. Then I tried to tackle it in a different direction. One of the easier ways to take the nth derivative of $(1-x^2)^{-1}$ is to decompose it into $\frac1{2(x+1)}-\frac1{2(x-1)}=\frac12\left(\frac1{x+1}-\frac1{x-1}\right)$, which is then easy to take the $n$th derivative of as it is essentially only power rule (derivatives of both $x+1$ and $x-1$ are $1$ so chain rule won't affect anything here). My thought is to maybe decompose $\frac1{1-x^3}$ in a similar fashion, but this might result in imaginary terms popping up. Even so, is this strategy viable for calculating the $n$th derivative of $f(x)=(1-x^3)^{-1}=\frac1{1-x^3}$? If not, what other strategies can I apply to solve this problem?

Comment: In general, $1/n \sum_{k=1}^n 1/(1-\omega^k x)=1/(1-x^n)$ where $\omega$ is a $n$th root of unity.

Comment: @Eric Thank you for that, but I was mainly wondering whether or not the strategy I mentioned is viable for finding the $n$th derivative of $f(x)=(1-x^3)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a bad idea actually.  Let $\zeta = e^{2\pi i/3}$ and $\bar \zeta = e^{-2\pi i/3}$ be the complex-valued roots of $z^3 - 1 = 0$.  Then $1-x^3$ admits the factorization $(1-x)(1-x/\zeta)(1 - x/\bar\zeta)$ and the subsequent partial fraction decomposition
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x^3} = \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{1-x} + \frac{1}{1-x/\zeta} + \frac{1}{1-x/\bar \zeta}\right).$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
f^{(n)}(x) &= \frac{n!}{3} \left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^{n+1}} + \frac{1}{(1-x/\zeta)^{n+1} \zeta^n} + \frac{1}{(1-x/\bar\zeta)^{n+1}\bar \zeta^n} \right) \\
&= \frac{n!}{3} \left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^{n+1}} + \frac{\zeta}{(\zeta-x)^{n+1}} + \frac{\bar \zeta}{(\bar \zeta - x)^{n+1}} \right) \\
&= \frac{n!}{3} \frac{((\zeta-x)(\bar \zeta-x))^{n+1} +  (1-x)^{n+1}(\zeta (\bar \zeta - x)^{n+1} + \bar \zeta (\zeta - x)^{n+1})}{(1-x^3)^{n+1}} \\
&= \frac{n!}{3} \frac{(1+x+x^2)^{n+1} + (1-x)^{n+1} g_{n+1}(x)}{(1-x^3)^{n+1}}, 
\end{align}$$
where
$$\begin{align}
g_n(x) &= \zeta(\bar \zeta - x)^n + \bar \zeta(\zeta - x)^n \\
&= \zeta \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-x)^k \bar \zeta^{n-k} + \bar \zeta \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-x)^k \zeta^{n-k} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (\bar \zeta^{n-k-1} + \zeta^{n-k-1})(-x)^k \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n 2 \cos \frac{2 \pi (n-k-1)}{3} \binom{n}{k} (-x)^k.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac1{1-x^3}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{3k},\quad|x|<1$$
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac1{1-x^3}=\sum_{k=\lceil n/3\rceil}^\infty\frac{(3k)!}{(3k-n)!}\,x^{3k-n}$$
$$n=3m-2:\qquad\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac1{1-x^3}=\sum_{k=m}^\infty\frac{(3k)!}{(3k-3m+2)!}\,x^{3k-3m+2}$$
$$=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(3j+3m)!}{(3j+2)!}\,x^{3j+2}$$
$$n=3m-1:\qquad\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac1{1-x^3}=\sum_{k=m}^\infty\frac{(3k)!}{(3k-3m+1)!}\,x^{3k-3m+1}$$
$$=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(3j+3m)!}{(3j+1)!}\,x^{3j+1}$$
$$n=3m:\qquad\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac1{1-x^3}=\sum_{k=m}^\infty\frac{(3k)!}{(3k-3m)!}\,x^{3k-3m}$$
$$=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(3j+3m)!}{(3j)!}\,x^{3j}$$